# Monit Alert with Multiple URLs

Tags: monit

I've got a monit setup to http check several subdomains of an http server.

Currently, they are multiple check host statements that look like this:

```
CHECK HOST a.example.com with address 1.2.3.4
 if failed url https://blah then alert
CHECK HOST b.example.com with address 1.2.3.4
 if failed url https://blah then alert
```

It's possible for either the entire server to be in a failed state, or for any subdomain.

In instances where the entire server is down, or if we've lost a load balancer, I would like not to receive notifications for a dozen individual subdomains.

Can a single failed test disable a subsequent test? Is it possible to  group all of these URLs under a single HOST section and combine them in an OR ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can a single failed test disable a subsequent test?

To my knowledge, this is not possible with Monit.

> Is it possible to group all of these URLs under a single HOST section and combine them in an OR ?

Yes, you can simply add as many `if` rules as you can (or your HDD will store ;-)). Since every `if` is a rule by its own, it automagically acts as `OR` connected.

I always link them to my httpd process like so:

```
check process "nginx" with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
    start   program = "/bin/systemctl start   nginx.service"
    restart program = "/bin/systemctl restart nginx.service"
    stop    program = "/bin/systemctl stop    nginx.service"

    if failed
        host glances.boppy.eu
        port 443
        protocol https
        request "/.well-known/nitmo-ping.txt"
        with ssl options {verify: enable}
        ssl certificate valid 5 days
    then alert
```

So it's not only checking availability of the domain/path/file, it also informs me if my silly cronjob to renew the certificates didn't do its job.